# Need to get count of same contact in 2 account

Tags: apex, trigger, account, business-logic

Requirement- I have 2 accounts (source and target) and i want to get the count of same contact name in target account
Ex- Ac1 ==> {con1,con2,con3 con4}
AC2 ==> {con1,con2,con4}
then count should be 3.
i have written below code.Its working but not sure if its good code or we can write better way.

```
public class AccountContactMapping {

public static void getCon(Id sourceId,string targetId) {
map<id,set<contact>> sourceMap = new map<id,set<contact>>();    
set<string> srcon = new set<string>();      
    list<contact> conlist = [select id,lastname from contact where accountid =:sourceId];
    system.debug('conlst-->'+conlist);
    for(contact con:conlist) {
        srcon.add(con.lastname);
        system.debug('srcon-->'+srcon);
    }
    //sourceMap.put(sourceId,srcon);
    system.debug('sourceMap--->'+sourceMap);
    integer i=0;
    list<contact> conlist2 = [select id,lastname from contact where accountid =:targetId];
     for(contact con:conlist2) {
         
         if(srcon.contains(con.lastname)) {
             i++;
         }
     }
    system.debug('Same contacts are-->'+i);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine. You can enhance it by using single query instead 2.

```
map<String, Integer> nameCounterMap = new map<String, Integer>();

for(Contact con : [select ID,LastName from Contact where AccountId =:sourceId or AccountId = :targetId]){
    nameCounterMap.put(con.LastName, 
        nameCounterMap.containsKey(con.LastName) ? nameCounterMap.get(con.LastName) + 1 : 1);
}

Integer total = 0;
for(String conName : nameCounterMap.keySet()){
    if(nameCounterMap.get(conName) == 2){
        total ++;
    }
}
```